# call management in android

Tags: java, android, phone-call

I'm looking for a developers guide or good tutorials on phone call management In android.
What I want to do is to detect incoming phone call activate a custom activity in which I can answer, reject and hangup a phone call.

For some reason I'm having trouble finding good information about it in google.

Answer (score 0):

You have to interact with the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) (I'm using the code you can find in the "Miscellaneous" section [here](https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android/wiki/android)).

Comment: This seems like a way to get the status of the incoming call. Is there away to change it (Answer/reject/hangup)?

Comment: I found some code at  http://www.androidsnippets.com/automatic-phone-caller. It seems you have to instantiate internal classes (derived from com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony) to access phone calls directly. I haven't tested it myself yet. On the other hand, you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html to interact at a higher/better documented level. But I can't say it's well documented either.

Comment: I also found http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java which seems to document a bit more of that interface.